# Adding dependency to conda env

Tags: python, conda

I want to run a python program which was written in python2.7. There is a conda environment but it installs the newest networkx module which is not compatible with python2.7. I have the appropriate version of networkx (decorater.py) but I'm not sure how I should add it. All the scripts include `'import networkx'` so I've tried to define networkx as decorater.py in the dependencies list of the conda env file (yml), but I get a ResolvePackageNotFound: error. I guess I could go through all the scripts and execute the decorator.py file instead of importing networkx but I was wondering if there is an easier way to add it to the conda env.

Comment: Have you tried `conda install networkx python=2.7`?

Comment: @alani, yes I deleted the networkx dependency from the environment file and ran the install python=2.7 command but I got `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a dedicated environment for this, something like

```bash
conda create -n networkx_py27 networkx python=2.7
```